# Can anyone help with solving this integral?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I would like to solve this indefinite integral. I was practicing figuring out integrals when this one stumped me. WolframAlpha seems to have calculated it using some numerical method. I feel like this should be solvable.

$$\int \frac{2^{x^2}}{5^x}dx$$

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This can be reduced to a primitive of $\exp(x^2)$, which cannot be expressed in terms of usual functions.

Answer (score 3):

Write it as $\int \exp[-(ax-bx^2)]dx$, complete the square in the exponent and change variable to $t=\sqrt{b}(x-a/2b)$. Then recognize that the integral is an error function.

Comment: So: to "practice figuring out integrals" take your problems from a list appropriate for your level.  If you just pick them at random, you will get non-elementary antiderivatives pretty quickly.